# constructing JSON from oneToMany dataset

Tags: java, json

I have this model in the database

A **Country** has many **States**, which has many **Cities**, which each has a **Mayor** . The bold being independent tables with ref keys to all They are also Java Classes/Models.

I'd like to construct a JSON in this format for a JS library

```
    {
  "Country1": [
    "State1":[
          "City1":[
                 "Mr.Mayor"
            ]
           "City2":[
                  "Mrs.Mayor"
              ]             
            ], 
  "State2": [
         "City1":[
                 "Mr.Mayor"
            ]
        .....
```

Currently implemented as a query that joins all of them into one list of all Countries and their states and cities. Then while looping over the result set from the query construct the above JSON. What is the best/fastest way? I am not using an ORM or JPA but MVC and queries are in DAO

Answer (score 1):

Try building a `Multimap<Country, Multimap<State, Map<City, Mayor>>>`. Be careful to use the correct types while serializing and deserializing. For example, if you are using `Gson`, you will need to use the `TypeToken` class.

Comment: Can you elaborate on serialization

Comment: That depends on what library you are using to (a) construct the JSON object, and (b) to reconstruct the Java object from the JSON strings.